# Run script on remote machine via telnet (not SSH)

Tags: remote-access, remote, scripts, telnet

I need to somehow run a script which resides on a remote machine running Ubuntu.
SSH or any other connection type that requires complex encryption is not possible.
The client that will connect to the remote machine is only capable of opening a port and sending and receiving strings.
Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: "The client that will connect to the remote machine is only capable of opening a port and sending and receiving strings." What is this client? Is it a Linux box? An embedded system? Do you have any control over the strings sent to/received by the open port? Please detail your scenario.

Comment: The box is by AMX and has VxWorks embedded. I have full control over the strings being sent and can read all strings being received. I just need to know if I can run scripts on the remote Ubuntu machine via telnet.

Answer (score 1):

At the remote machine (Ubuntu) install telnetd, if it's not already installed.

At the client side you could implement the following:

1. Open a socket to the Ubuntu machine (`<ubuntu-IP-address>:23`).
2. Listen and wait for the login prompt (something like `<hostname> login:`), then send the username.
3. Listen and wait for the password prompt (`Password:`), then send the password.
4. Listen and wait for the command prompt (`<username>@<hostname>:~$`), then send the command to run your script.

Comment: G'day Eric,  
Thanks for that.  
Since my original post I had already gotten that far on my own.  
As an experiment I wrote a script to launch gedit.  
The script works on the server side but if I run the script from the client side I receive the following error.  
  
(gedit:2765): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:

I presume this is the output from gedit being returned to the client rather than executing on the server?
Is this a correct assumption? If so, how can I force gedit to run on the server? 

Thanks again  
  
Matt

Comment: Sorry for the blocked text.  I can't seem to get the markdown to work.

Comment: @MatthewTaylor Ahh... Now it's a completely different question. In order to open any graphical application the DISPLAY variable must be set. Run `export DISPLAY=:0.0` before running gedit.